# Conditional Sum of subtotals from values in Table Y, display with values in Table X. Then generate totals based on conditions from Table X

Tags: mysql, sql

I have Table X:

```
| key | name   | drcr | drcr_other | coa_type | coa_header |
|-----|--------|------|------------|----------|------------|
| 1   | assets | dr   | cr         | head     |            |
| 2   | cash   | dr   | cr         | sub      | assets     |
| 3   | bank   | dr   | cr         | sub      | assets     |
| 4   | equity | cr   | dr         | head     |            |
| 5   | income | cr   | dr         | sub      | equity     |
```

I have Table Y:

```
| key | account | drcr | amount |
|-----|---------|------|--------|
| 1   | bank    | dr   | 1000   |
| 2   | income  | cr   | 1000   |
| 3   | cash    | dr   | 100    |
| 4   | bank    | cr   | 100    |
```

I'd like to generate a query such that it shows:
Where assets and equity are totals (header rows) of their sub accounts. For example income is a sub account of equity and since income is 1000, equity should be 1000.

```
| account | amount |
|---------|--------|
| bank    | 900    |
| income  | 1000   |
| cash    | 100    |
| assets  | 1000   |
| equity  | 1000   |
```

As of now I can get the bank and cash to sum up as those have amounts to add in Table Y, I am unsure of how to add the totals for assets (the sum of cash and bank) and equity (the sum of income). Currently I am summing everything by using the following statement...

```
SELECT name,
SUM( 
    IF(account = name AND Y.drcr = X.drcr, amount, 0) - IF(account = name AND Y.drcr = X.drcr_other, amount, 0)
) 
AS Total FROM `Y`, `X`
GROUP BY name ORDER BY name
```

I was thinking I could sum the totals by using the coa_header and coa_type fields. I am new to MySQL and I'm just playing around, this is just a personal summer project I am tinkering with. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

This is all in MySQL 5.0.11

Comment: Why is there not line `equity  1000` ?

Comment: First you need to `Join` the tables using `INNER JOIN`

Comment: I just forgot to add the equity line when I was making this sample data, sorry. I'll add it now.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand how you get 900 for `bank`, because there are 1100 each of credit and debit.  If you subtract their sums, of course you get 0.

What I can do is show you how to make the subtraction possible.  Then you can supply your own query to the technique.

The trick is known as *folding*: for each row, you create *N*.  The column that you want to add/subtract becomes two columns (in your case, N=2), and then you can just subtract them.

Here's the basic idea:

```
select account, side
           , case side when 'dr' then amount else 0 end as debit
           , case side when 'cr' then amount else 0 end as credit
    from (
         select 'dr' as side UNION select 'cr'
    ) as U
    cross join T
    where account = 'bank'
    ;
account     side        debit       credit    
----------  ----------  ----------  ----------
bank        cr          0           1000      
bank        cr          0           100       
bank        dr          1000        0         
bank        dr          100         0
```

We can compress that to one row thus:

```
select account
       , sum( case side when 'dr' then amount else 0 end ) as debit
       , sum( case side when 'dr' then amount else 0 end ) as debit
from (
     select 'dr' as side UNION select 'cr'
) as U
cross join T
where account = 'bank'
group by account
;
account     debit       debit     
----------  ----------  ----------
bank        1100        1100
```

Your challenge is to join your tables in such a way as (I guess) the debit side is 100.  Then the subtraction will come easily.  :-)

HTH.